# Wrapping div is not resized when inner image scales (a result of window resize)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want my images to resize as the window height changes while keeping the containing div shrink wrapping the image. I tried using:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://akamaicovers.oreilly.com/images/9780596806767/cat.gif" alt="">
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 90%;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work as expected. The `div` doesn't shrink. It actually does once I play around with the css properties in debugger.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhyv9/) (try resizing the result panel)

**Update:**

Now this is strange. Since I first posted this question the browser behaviour changed. Originally (Chrome) when I resized the window the image would shrink proportionally as expected but the wrapping div would keep its original width. What happens now (Chrome update?) is that the image doesn't shrink horizontally, and the div also.

I tried it with the latest Safari and Firefox. Both shrink the image but keep original div width. So please be kind to check your solutions on other browsers as well.

**Update #2:**

The div has to stay of block type as I need to place other elements in the corners of the image.

Comment: I don't know this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXLg4/) is something you want or not. I made a fullscreen background with responsive option. Btw, it's using JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this little hack worked for me. To my understanding it forces the browser to redraw/reflow its contents. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhyv9/40/). I can't figure out why this isn't done automatically by the browser. Tested on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    $(".thumb").each(function() {
        this.style.display = "none";
        this.offsetWidth;
        this.style.display= "inline-block";
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'll have to resort to JavaScript:

```
$(window).on('resize', function (){ 
    $('div').width($('img').width());
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhyv9/20/)**

Comment: Yeah, was trying to avoid js.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to keep your image `max-height` to be 100%. Thats it.

Here is the [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/zhyv9/24/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://akamaicovers.oreilly.com/images/9780596806767/cat.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 90%;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated `CSS` for the `img` class to make the image fit the full div. 
Here is the [working solution for the edit](http://jsfiddle.net/zhyv9/30/).

```
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: You might want to set `display: block` on the image to get rid of some added inline spacing under the image.

Comment: oops.. I missed that. Updated. Nice catch. -@user1846192

Comment: Perfect! Could you please explain why this works and the original code doesn't? Did you mean `max-height` or `max-width` in the first sentence?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer and the efforts, kindly accept it with a green tick and upvote. Thank you - @Xyand

Comment: The only issue with your solution was that the div had to be converted from its inherent block display to inline. Now for the image, making it to a block display meant that it was a perfect fit inside the div. max-height and max-width meant that when the window was scaled down, the div with image could also stretch. Hope this helps. - @Xyand

Comment: So in fact it has nothing to do with `max-width`/`max-height`. Settings `display: inline;` does the trick.

Comment: Yes. `display:inline;` is sufficient, but ideally if you work on mulitiple images and streching issues if they do occur, `max-height` for the images should be used. - @Xyand

Comment: Hey you forgot to award your bounty. :) - @Xyand

Comment: I have to wait 24 hrs. But I'm not sure that your solution is sufficient. I need the wrapper to be of block type (for placing other contained elements). Anyhow, if `inline` is the key here then please make it clear in your answer. It is hard to understand from the text.

Comment: Yes it is the `display:inline;` that should be used for this case, but as you mentioned that you need to make this a block, I suggest you to create a block wrapper `div` and place this inline div inside it as it is going to accomodate the images if I assume from your scenario, then all the contained elements will be placed inside the main parent block div. - @Xyand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30534/discussion-between-xyand-and-nathan-lee)

Comment: Odd.. Even now, this doesn't seem to work for `inline-block` elements. In chromium and opera I get [slightly different behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097704/make-element-same-width-as-dynamically-sized-image?noredirect=1#comment57939818_35097704) from what the OP described. Firefox seems the same.

Comment: @gandalf3 - Can you share more information as well as link to the issue?

Comment: @NKL The question I linked has a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/601a5uqv/) which demonstrates the behavior I've noticed (albeit with some extra stuff on the side)

Answer (score 1):

I have had a bit of a go at your fiddle but I don't think browsers will change the width of a `div` based on the width of the image inside it changing its width, I have tried a few things but couldn't get it to work.

I can however suggest another approach to placing elements in the corners of your auto re-sizing image. Instead of placing these elements inside a `div` which is also holding the image, you could just float the image and float some `div`'s with a fixed width to the right and the left of the image, and then make those `div`'s cut into the image by setting some negative margins on them.

Here's an example <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhyv9/37/)</kbd> demonstrating this approach. You'll see that the images stay in the corners of the main image when you resize the result window (and thereby changing the size of the main image).

**HTML**

```
<div class="right">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
<img src="http://akamaicovers.oreilly.com/images/9780596806767/cat.gif" alt="" />
<div class="left">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    height: 90%;
    float: left;
}
div {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 90%;
}
div.left {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
div.right {
    margin-right: -40px;
}
div > img {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
div > img:last-child {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: It looks like an interesting direction. However, in the end I do need to wrap it inside a container as part of a larger structure (gallery). Ideas?

Comment: No ideas, I don't think CSS will let you re-size a wrapper element based on the image inside it re-sizing, I think you'll just have to use JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

you want to give your image width to 100%. Use this.

```
img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I need width to be proportional to height. Not 100% of containing element.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a width and height for the div in %, it resizes according to the page size. And the image size in % is relative to the div width and height. I have kept the div height at 90% of the available space and width at 50%. The image is at 90% both height and width, so that you can see the re-sizing of both image and div sections.

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

 div {
height: 90%;
background-color: black;
width:50%;
}

img {
height: 90%;
width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your css written for image purpose

```
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to resize image by height but keep proportional size?

If so, use this:

```
img {
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

You might want to use display: block; as well, depending on your needs.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zhyv9/38/

Comment: Now try resizing the window and see what happens

Comment: Image resizes proportionally, still.

Comment: Not with latest Chrome. With Firefox the image is resized but the wrapping div isn't (my original problem)

Comment: Use display: block; instead. If you need to position it to the left, use float: left;

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/zhyv9/39/), with the Img tag self close that may cause error some times..,

and If the image have specified size height and width then it will also resize, and the corresponding div height increases/decrease as 90% when I zoom-in/zoom-out

I hope this is the answer, as I have understood wrapping and re-sizing,
Please reply if not working..

Comment: Hi, it didn't really answer my question.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, If other way I see, you want image to resize automatically with size of div? if that is the case you must use JavaScript with the browser size changed event.. and assign parents width to image width

Comment: I want image height to be re-sized with div (works) and width to be set proportionally. But I want the div to shrink and occupy only the image space.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/zhyv9/41/
but imge have 3px transparency in footer else woking fine now.. :)

Comment: Sorry, the image isn't scaled when window is resized.

Comment: on Resize is not called in CSS, it is drawn on the loading time stats available.. if in that case use jQuery answer given by Tomas Kirda that will do.. will post if come across something new.. :)

Comment: See my answer (+original CSS). It does the trick. No escape from js though

Comment: Old trick was to reload location.reload(); but its not good in current scenario, as we use ajax and reloading the page is bad custom.. so jQuery comes handy..